# can't get shares count data from addThis API using <script/>

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, addthis

After trying to find a solution for this problerm in a couple hours. I decided to ask the experts who are on Stackoverflow.

Using the same script code. It's working for Facebook API, but not working for addThis API. Anyone can help?

I just need addThis Total Shares Count, and put in on my HTML `element` on my site.

Thanks a lot.

```js
  var sum = 0,
      link = encodeURI('http://twitter.com');


$.getJSON('http://api-public.addthis.com/url/shares.json?url='+link,function(addthis) {

    sum += parseFloat(addthis.shares);

    $('.at').html(sum);

  });

  $.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/?id='+link,function(fb) {

    sum += parseFloat(fb.shares);

    $('.fb').html(sum);

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='fb'>fb script not working.</div>

<div class='at'>addThis script not working.</div>
```

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? The access-control-allow-origin header is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are making a XHR request from a different domain that what you are on. Hence the issue here is CORS. When you will try making that request than on the browser console you should get the error

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Modern browsers block Cross origin requests due to security reasons. 
For better understanding read more on that [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)

Comment: No, i do request in the same domain. I always can't get shares data with addThis API. But if i change it with Facebook API it's working (code is same)

Comment: thats because `http://api-public.addthis.com` doesnt allow CORS request and fb does.